# C# application not running with exit code -1073740791 (0xc0000409)

Tags: c#, c++

I have created a C# application, having 3 projects:

1. C# project [startup]
2. CLI project
3. Native C++ project [with VC90 compiler (Visual Studio 2008)]

Here, I have a simple class in C++ project which I am exporting and calling a very simple method of this class from CLI project.

The code builds fine, but once I try to run it, it exits with the following output messages:

> The program '[6088] VS2012_ConsoleApp.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409). The program '[6088] VS2012_ConsoleApp.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code
>   -1073740791 (0xc0000409).

It works fine if I am creating a class object in the heap.
The error is coming if I create static object instance.

```
// WORKING CODE [Object creation on heap]   
    NativeClass* cls = new NativeClass();
    int returnVal = cls->Add(A, B);


// This code is not working
    NativeClass cls;
    int returnVal = cls.Add(A, B);
    return returnVal;
```

Comment: Could you post the class definition?

Comment: 0xc0000409 = `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`

Comment: @Alex: **C++ Header file**

 '#ifdef NATIVE_DLL
    #define CLASS_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define CLASS_SPEC __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    
    class CLASS_SPEC NativeClass
    {
    public:
     int Add(int a, int b);    
};' 

**CLI Project code**

' int Class1::Add(int A, int B)
{
 // WORKING CODE [Object creation on heap 
 /*NativeClass* cls = new NativeClass();
 int returnVal = cls->Add(A, B);*/
 
 // This code is not working
 NativeClass cls; // This line is the culprit
 return returnVal;
}'

Comment: @wj32  I know that this is buffer overrun. But I do not know the reason behind it / fix for the same.   Same code used to work with previous version of Visual Studio.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks...

Comment: Unlikely the code actually looks that way, especially since the original code was a memory leak.  You'll need to debug this.  Enable the unmanaged debugger, it will stop when the runtime pulls the plug.

Comment: How big an object is NativeClass? You are allocating on the stack in the second case which could cause a stack buffer overrun.